# Placing text over image slider?

Tags: css, image, text

I have a quick question regarding some CSS work on my website. I need help with putting some text on top of my image slider (www.ininkk.com) just like how it looks on the page banner here: http://www.instacool.com.au/white-ink-printing/ (where it says "white ink printing"). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok you have to put the text position to absolute , something like this :

```
.image { 
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
 }

 h2 { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 200px; 
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick codepen, need some styling but should get you started:

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/LkoEZz

```
<div class="img-bg">
  <h2>some text</h2>
</div>

h2{
  padding:100px;
}

.img-bg{
  background:url('http://nilestanner.com/codepen/expanding-hover-tabs/vista-1.jpg');
    height:500px;
}
```